# Elegant way of extracting substrings matching regex?

Tags: python, regex, compiler-construction, regex-greedy, bnf

Is there a nice way in Python to do:

- Check a String matches a set of regular expressions
- If yes: get the matching parts back as tuples.

So essentially I want a simple way to enter simple parser/scanner grammars, and simply extract all matching in a certain structure (e.g. tuples)

So suppose we have encoded in a String a country code, an city name and an index. We want to extract this:

```
input = "123-NEWYORK-[2]"
grammar = "<country,[0-9]+>-<city,[A-Z]*>-[<index,[0-9]*>"
res = HOW_TO_DO_THIS(input,grammar)
if res is None:
  print("Does not match")
else
  (countrycode,city,index) = res
```

Comment: check out this one buddy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239445/get-string-that-was-matched-by-regex/46239491#46239491

Comment: You need to use the `re` module; the question as it stands is too broad, as it basically asks for a tutorial for that module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With python3 you can do, note that the regex  has been modified:

```
import re
input = "123-NEWYORK-[2]"
grammar = r"(?P<country>[0-9]+)-(?P<city>[A-Z]*)-(?P<index>\[[0-9]*\])"
res = re.findall(grammar, input)
if not res:
  print("Does not match")
else:
  (countrycode,city,index) = res[0]
  print(countrycode)
```

Modifications:

- The correct regex would be [(?P[0-9]+)-(?P[A-Z]*)-(?P[[0-9]*])](https://regex101.com/r/GkStec/1/)
- The syntax for regex module in python is `re.findall(patter, input_string)`. Not the opposite.
- `if not x` is easier (and more generic) than `if x is None`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code. This is just for simple text lookup but you can extend according to your scenario

```
import re
f=open('sample.txt',"w")
f.write("<p class = m>babygameover</p>")
f.close()
f=open('sample.txt','r')
string = "<p class = m>(.+?)</p>" # regular expression
pattern = re.compile(string) # compiling
text = f.read()
search = re.findall(pattern,text) # searching 
print search
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. findall is finding all occurrences of 1 regexp. I want all occurences of subregexps which are by themselves placed according to a certain bigger regexp (so in the case above <countrycode>-<city>[<index>].

Comment: @robert you can read the data from line by line and make it in a loop to do your stuff